# ошибка mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php

выскакивает ошибка

```
Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

вот код

```
    // создание строки запроса
$query =("INSERT INTO test1 (score, field1) VALUES(NOT NULL,?)");
// подготавливаем запрос
$stmt = $link->prepare($query); 
// привязываем к нему переменные
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['licscore'], $_POST['field_0']); 
//выполняем запрос
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: здесь делает NOT NULL, я стесняюсь спросить

Comment: без NOT NULL выдает ошибку Column 'score' cannot be null

Comment: если выдает ошибку, то это значит что в $_POST['licscore'] у тебя null. Л - логика.

Comment: и мне надо чтобы первая строка была обязательной, насколько я понял это делается с помощью NOT NULL

Comment: ты все правильно понял. только NOT NULL делает **колонку** НЕ обязательной, при создании таблицы. А в этом месте ее писать вообще бессмысленно

Comment: то есть первая колонка у тебя сейчас обязательная. **то есть код делает ровно то о чем ты его попросил**: сообщает что значение для **обязательной** колонки **отсутстует**

Comment: но вместо того чтобы ввести свое **обязательне**  значение, ты начиаешь писать какую-то ерунду

Comment: то есть в VALUES мне надо записать ($licscore, ?);

Comment: о господи. ты этому коду вообще кто? Кто заставил тебя его писать? Ты явно не понимаешь ни одного слова здесь, ставя наугад в случайном порядке.

Comment: @Ипатьев че то ржу с твоих комментов периодически :D

Comment: повторяю ещё раз. читай **внимательно** что я тебе пишу. если выдает ошибку, то это значит что в $_POST['licscore'] у тебя **null**. то есть база данных тебя **предупреждает о том о чем ты сам ее попросил** - что в первую колонку ты не передаешь никакое значение.

Comment: то есть ты должен сорваться и роняя тапки бежать разибраться **ПОЧЕМУ** в $_POST['licscore'] у тебя null. А не писать всякую ересь в запрос

Comment: все уже поставил в таблица галочку под NULL, теперь ошибку не выдает, получается чтобы сделать на сайте обязательное поле надо в таблице поставить NULL, а в коде ничего не менять?

Comment: о господи. надо сначала определиться, обязательное поле, или нет.

Comment: ты наверное не понимаешь, что такое обязательное поле. обязательное поле - это когда тебе пишет ошибку, если ты ничего в поле не записал.

Comment: а если надо чтобы не было ошибки, это значит что поле не обязательное

Comment: поэтому ты должен сначала сам между себя решить

Comment: обязательное у тебя поле или нет

Answer (score -2):

В строке:

```
$query =("INSERT INTO test1 (score, field1) VALUES(NOT NULL,?)");
```

вы пытаетесь в таблицу test1 вставить строку со значениями для полей (столбцов таблицы) score и field1. То есть пытаетесь заполнить два поля. В куске `VALUES(NOT NULL,?)` вы как раз передаёте эти два значения. Первое: not null - то есть, значение должно быть не пустым. Второй параметр и значение будет подставлен позже из переменной вместо вопросительного знака.

Вот только в момент подстановки в строке:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['licscore'], $_POST['field_0']);
```

вы почему-то передаёте уже не два, а три значения: строчку "ss", и значения двух переменных: `$_POST['licscore']` и `$_POST['field_0']`.

То есть запрашивали два, а передаёте ТРИ значения. Ну и важно всё-таки прислушаться к тому, что вам писали выше в комментариях.

P. S. В тексте ошибки "stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement" вам как раз об этом сказано. Не знаете английского, хотя бы переведите в яндексе или гугле текст ошибки.

**Upd:** Самое главное: в команде на вставку данных в таблицу, в той части команды, где передаются значения: `VALUES(NOT NULL,?)` not null использовать некорректно. Нельзя. Читайте документацию, ссылки на которую вам дали выше в комментариях.

Comment: Ты б хоть прочитал комменты @Ипатьев про использование `NOT NULL` в совершенно непредназначенном для этого месте.

Comment: @u_mulder Прочитал подробно, В комментариях всё написано более, чем подробно. Пусть задавший вопрос разбирается. Другое дело, что когда разберётся и исправит на два вопросительных знака, а позже передаст три параметра - ошибка про не совпадающее количество параметров запрошенных и переданных - не исчезнет.

Comment: Может тогда стоило написать что `NOT NULL` здесь вообще не к месту, а не вот это вот "значение должно быть не пустым".

Comment: Так об этом уже написали, да ещё и дали ссылки на документацию.

Comment: Ладно, тут не достучаться.

Comment: Да не вопрос. Внесу поправку в ответ. Просто не считал нужным писать то, что человеку уже разжевали и в рот положили.

Comment: Ты отвечаешь на вопрос, почему читающий ответ должен потом еще идти в комменты и оттуда что-то добирать? Ответь от начала до конца - где неверно, что сделать, чтобы пофиксить.

Comment: Вот странно. Из ответа совершенно очевидно, что ты не знаешь ни mysql, ни mysqli. Зачем садиться писать ответ по технологиям, которых ты не понимаешь?

Comment: @ИпатьевНу, конечно. Использую в проектах, но не знаю. ))